# Save state of custom view inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-custom-view

First, some background information. I have an `Activity` that hosts several `Fragment`s; these are hidden and shown such that only one `Fragment` is visible at a time. Each `Fragment` hosts several custom `View`s that I call `IncrementCounter`s. Those views display a number and increment that number by 1 when tapped.

Each of the `Fragment`s has `setRetainInstance(true)` called on it when it is created in my `Activity`. When the `Activity` is created, I check to see if the `Fragment`s exist; if they do, I store a reference to them; if not, I create a new instance, like this:

```
autonFragment = (AutonomousScoutingFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag("auton");
teleopFragment = (TeleoperatedScoutingFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag("teleop");
postMatchFragment = (PostMatchScoutingFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag("post_match");
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
if (autonFragment == null) {
    Log.d("onCreate", "autonFragment is null!");
    autonFragment = new AutonomousScoutingFragment();
    autonFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    ft.add(R.id.scouting_fragment_container, autonFragment, "auton")
        .hide(autonFragment);
}
if (teleopFragment == null) {
    Log.d("onCreate", "teleopFragment is null!");
    teleopFragment = new TeleoperatedScoutingFragment();
    teleopFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    ft.add(R.id.scouting_fragment_container, teleopFragment, "teleop")
        .hide(teleopFragment);
}
if (postMatchFragment == null) {
    Log.d("onCreate", "postMatchFragment is null!");
    postMatchFragment = new PostMatchScoutingFragment();
    postMatchFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    ft.add(R.id.scouting_fragment_container, postMatchFragment,
    "post_match").hide(postMatchFragment);
}
ft.commit();
```

One problem I have is that after every orientation change, it seems as though the `Fragment`s aren't actually being retained, as ever time I see debug prints stating that they are all null. This may be realted to my bigger problem; I'm not sure.

I am trying to figure out how to maintain the value of the number stored in each `IncrementCounter` across configuration changes, specifically rotation. I have overridden `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` in `IncrementCounter`. When I rotate my device, I see that `onSaveInstanceState()` is called on all of the `IncrementCounter`s I have in my `Fragment`s. However, the corresponding `onRestoreInstanceState()` is never called, and my `IncrementCounter`s do not have their states restored. What is the proper way to handle something like this? I've been banging my head against my desk for hours about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Fragments have the setRetainInstance(true), they will not be destroyed on a rotation.  The Activity will be destroyed, and the Fragments will be detached until a new Activity is created.  However, the Fragments will go through the onCreateView() method again, so you would need to restore their IncrementCounters.

Also, you can save state in onSaveInstanceState(), and then restore it in onCreate(), onCreateView(), and several other methods that are all passed that same bundle as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but one of my problems is that the Fragments seemingly aren't surviving across configuration changes. Am I doing the right thing to retrieve them upon the recreation of my activity?